# jQuery Carousel error

Tags: jquery

**My JavaScript Code**:

```
$("#carousel").jCarouselLite({
    visible: 4,
    btnNext: ".next",
    btnPrev: ".prev",
    circular: false
});
```

Why do i get this error?

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of undefined
widthjcarousellite_1.0.1.min.js:1
$.fn.jCarouselLitejcarousellite_1.0.1.min.js:1
e.extend.eachjquery.min.js:16
e.fn.e.eachjquery.min.js:16
$.fn.jCarouselLitejcarousellite_1.0.1.min.js:1
(anonymous function)home.js:4
f.extend._Deferred.e.resolveWithjquery.min.js:16
e.extend.readyjquery.min.js:16
c.addEventListener.B
```

Comment: Can you please provide some generated HTML to work with, or an URL where we can see this in action

Comment: when you change the language at the top, the error occurs

Comment: Why did you accept Mandeeps answer? First of, it wasnt the answer to your question, second, I provided that answer first.. Did you fix it yourself? Please see my other answer, I spent some time figuring it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I may have found your problem, it's probably ASP related.

When the language is changed, there are no elements in the `<ul>` in `<div id='carousel'>`. I'm almost certain that this is causing Carousel to fail. Please make sure this code: `<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="Repeater_Videos">` always returns elements, and then try again.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this because I forgot to put the items I wanted in the carousel in a list (<ul>, <li>).  I just had them in divs under the main div.  Dumb, but a better error message would have been helpful.

Answer (score 0):

`<div id="carousel1">` should be `<div id="carousel">`?

The error shows you that the carousel script can not find the element it's supposed to work on. You specify `#carousel` in the in the intiation of the carousel script, but I only see a div with Id `carousel1`

Comment: sorry edited that, i was testing to see what was causing the issue, typo

Answer (score 0):

You have initiated the carousal for #carousal.

But div is having id #carousal1.

They should be same.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this structure:

`<ul id="carousel">
    <li><img src="x.jpg"/></li>
    <li><img src="y.jpg"/></li>
    <li><img src="z.jpg"/></li>
</ul>`