# Bootstrap: "Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of undefined" error with carousel

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using multiple in carousels Bootstrap:

```
<div id="carousel-586" class="carousel slide carousel-block" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carousel-586" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-586" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-586" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="item active">
            <img src="..." alt="...">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="..." alt="...">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="..." alt="...">
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-586" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-586" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

However, I'm receiving an error in JavaScript:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of undefined

I've found a few similar problems ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8615840/jquery-carousel-error), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29027830/getting-cannot-read-property-offsetwidth-of-undefined-with-bootstrap-carousel)), but they don't appear applicable to me.

Despite the errors the carousel functions without problems, but I'd prefer to know what's causing the errors and fix them.

Any suggestions would be great.

Comment: It would probably be easier to see the error if you could set up an example either here or in jsFiddle

Comment: First search result: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29027830/getting-cannot-read-property-offsetwidth-of-undefined-with-bootstrap-carousel.  Have you tried that one?

Comment: Hi @pep, please refer to the two "similar problems" in the post.

Comment: Ah,  missed those links, they're kinda hard to see.

Comment: Hi @adeneo, I can do one better; here's the [work-in-progress development version of the application](http://www.tobook.org.uk/users/login). You should see a whole heap of carousels to the right, under the title: "Featured Hotels".

Comment: you have 2 carousels with the same ID

Comment: Hi @nolawipetros, do you mind sharing those IDs? I can't find them. All of the hotels are (or should be) unique.

Answer (score 0):

I found this question googling for the same issue. I have three different carousels that are displayed in the same container div element. I keep two of them hidden using jQuery.toggle() and only shows one of them at the time. The user can switch between the different carousels using a toggle button.

Though this question did not solve my problem, I thought I'd share my solution for the next person to encounter this problem. Apparently, you must have the class "active" set on all three carousels , independent of whether they are visible or not. I ended up with the following markup (essentially).

```
<div id="carousel-container">
    <div id="carousel1" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li class="active" data-target="#carousel1" data-slide-to="1"></li>
             <li data-target="#carousel1" data-slide-to="2"></li>
         </ol>
         <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
             <div class="item active">...</div>
             <div class="item">...</div>
         </div>
    </div>
    <div id="carousel2" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" style="display:none;">
         <ol class="carousel-indicators">
             <li class="active" data-target="#carousel2" data-slide-to="1"></li>
             <li data-target="#carousel2" data-slide-to="2"></li>
         </ol>
         <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
             <div class="item active">...</div>
             <div class="item">...</div>
         </div>
    </div>
    <div id="carousel3" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" style="display:none;">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li class="active" data-target="#carousel3" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel3" data-slide-to="2"></li>
         </ol>
         <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
             <div class="item active">...</div>
             <div class="item">...</div>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Point being is that despite that the divs with id "carousel2" and "carousel3" both has their display property set to "none", they still need to have an element with the class "active" (and corresponding navigation/carousel indicator). Hope it helps someone.